# How can I parse dates and calculate time differences in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell I have got two variables which contain dates. How can I parse the dates and calculate the time differences between two dates?

```
$date1="6/16/2014 3:52:48 PM"
$date2="6/16/2014 4:05:53 PM"
$between=$date2-$date1
$between #Need print: 00:13:05
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET's [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) type has a whole set of parsing methods, including some that allow you to specify a pattern, or multiple patterns, specifying the format you want. With a slight guess at the [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) you have:

```
$culture = Get-Culture
$format = "M'/'d'/'yyyy h':'mm':'ss tt"
$date1 = [DateTime]::ParseExact('6/16/2014 3:52:48 PM', $format, $culture)
$date2 = [DateTime]::ParseExact('6/16/2014 4:05:53 PM', $format, $culture)
```

If you subtract one [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) from another you'll get a `TimeSpan` instance, if you are using PowerShell V3 or latter, thus using .NET 4 this has considerably more formatting options (["standard"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) and ["custom"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) are both available, I use custom below) than earlier versions:

```
$between = $date2 - $date1
$between.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss")
```

> ```
> $between #Need print: 00:07:05
> ```

I think you'll find the difference is 13 minutes 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes. Sure 13 minutes. It's my mistake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I would just use get-date with the provided strings.  That will use the current culture and is much simpler.

```
$date1=get-date "6/16/2014 3:52:48 PM"
$date2=get-date "6/16/2014 4:05:53 PM"
$between=$date2-$date1
$between #Need print: 00:13:05
```

Answer (score 1):

$date1=[datetime]"6/16/2014 15:52:48"

$date2=[datetime]"6/16/2014 16:05:53"

(New-TimeSpan -Start $date1 -End $date2).ToString()

The output is **00:13:05**